# What is the best way to configure Apache or AWS to support a Rails multi tenancy application that allows each customer to have their own domain name?

Tags: apache-2.2, domain-name-system, cname-record, configuration

I'm building a Rails 3 SaaS site that allows for multi-tenancy.

When a customer signs up they put in their own domain name, e.g. `example.com.` I need `example.com` to point to my SaaS application and serve them their content.

**My questions are as follows:**

Do I need to create an Apache vhost for each customer using their own domain?

Is there an easier way with CNAME's to just have the customer point to the IP address of my server(s) that then forwards the request onto my application through some catch all vhost?

Would I be able to create the CNAME record for the customer so they don't have to do any setup?

Would this be a case better suited to Amazon Web Services?

Any help or explanation or corrections on my understanding of dns would be appreciated. I'm a developer so the server ops portion of this is a bit cloudy.

Comment: Maybe this will help: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

## **Short Answer:**

#### Apache:

Just use a catchall/wildcard vhost. Makes account provisioning way easier.

#### DNS:

Only allow subdomains, and have your customer's create a CNAME with their existing DNS provider.

#### AWS:

Using AWS or not will have no impact on the answer to the question at hand.

## **Long Answer:**

### Regarding the Apache vHost setup:

#### You have numerous options for the vhost setup, including:

,

- The two you already mentioned:

  1. individual vhosts
  2. one catchall vhost and handling it on the application level
- Numerous others. The Apache documentation linked to by LavaScornedOven 
  ( http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/mass.html ) is a good resource. How specifically you **should** do it really is beyond the scope of your question, and I'll explain why momentarily.

#### What type of vHost setup you choose however depends on your frontend application, and other factors:

- Is the new customer sign-up process using software you developed, or something canned?
- If the former, which method is going to be **easiest for you** to implement in your sign up process?
- If the latter, does it already have a provision for creating vhosts upon signup? If so, use whatever comes with the software.
- What do you want to happen if a non-customer points his domain to your IP? Consider this before using any kind of "catchall" vhost.
- **Ultimately, only you can determine which method will work best for you.**

### Regarding the DNS setup:

#### Firstly, something you should **definitely** avoid:

- CNAME at the zone apex. ie, `example.com` should NOT be a CNAME. It is okay if `www.example.com` is though.

#### Your options:

- **Leave it completely up to the customer:**

  1. Provide the customer an IP address to use
  2. Tell the customer to make an A record for their hostname pointing to that IP
  3. Optionally provide the customer a howto for creating the DNS record.
  4. **Pros:**

     - Easiest for you, at least upfront.
     - Does not require hosting anyone's DNS
  5. **Cons:**

     - Customers might have trouble following the directions
     - When/If you renumber and there is ever a new IP address, expect a massive influx of support tickets - no matter how much advance warning you give.
- **Have the customer use your NS records:**

  1. Tell your customers to change their domain's nameservers to yours with their registrar, or if they are using a subdomain, to delegate that subdomain to you using NS records.
  2. Optionally provide your customers detailed instructions how to do this
  3. Ensure that your signup process automatically creates the relevant zones in your DNS
  4. Optionally provide an interface for your customers to add other records to their zone, such as MX etc, or autoprovide them and host your customer's email too....
  5. **Pros:**

     - Simplest approach for your customers.
     - Avoids the whole worry about what happens if you have to renumber in the future
     - Avoids the whole CNAME conundrum
  6. **Cons:**

     - You now become a DNS hoster as well as an app hoster
     - Extra integration steps with your signup process

  **Only allow customers to use a subdomain (including possibly www)**

  1. Have the customer create a CNAME for that subdomain
  2. Optionally instruct the customer how to create an HTTP redirect from their bare domain to the subdomain.
  3. **Pros:**

     - Possibly the easiest approach.
     - Because many other hosted app services use this approach, the customer is more likely to be familiar with it, and therefore less likely to royally mess it up..
     - Like the NS approach, avoids problems during renumbering
  4. **Cons:**

     - Does NOT allow the customer to use their bare domain with your service
  5. **I strongly recommend this approach - for the sole reason that it is what customers are typically used to. You might want to consider allowing the other methods on a case-by-case basis.**

Comment: So what exactly will the CNAME do if they are still creating an HTTP redirect from their bare domain to the subdomain? I don't suppose a CNAME aliases the URL to make it appear that the site lives on their domain? Unfortunately the SaaS app is providing customers with what will be their company's primary website. I don't want them to have to tell their customers that their website is mycommpany.example.com. That's ugly.

Comment: There is a lot of misconception about what a CNAME is and isnt. CNAME has nothing to do with HTTP, and operates on domains NOT URLs (the two are anything but synonymous).  CNAME is strictly a DNS thing. It aliases one name to another. So when your customer's customer visits www.customer.tld, the IP address from hosted.example.com will be used. Does that make sense?  Real life example: do an nslookup or dig on www.google.com. (hint: its a CNAME alias for something else in google's domain)

Comment: That adds more clarity, thanks. I guess what I don't understand yet is you said www.customer.tld will use the IP address from hosted.example.com. What will that look like in the user's browser? Will they see hosted.example.com or www.customer.tld?

Comment: www.customer.tld

Comment: Because its a DNS thing, and NOT an HTTP redirect.

Comment: when you visit www.paypal.com do you see www.paypal.com in your address bar, or do you see www.paypal.com.akadns.net?  Because guess what, the former is a CNAME pointing to the latter...

Comment: Excellent! This should be exactly what I need. My app is setup to serve sites based on sub domains already so this is the route I'll likely go.

Comment: How will the http referrer look on this? hosted.example.com or www.customer.tld?

Comment: Neither. NO referrer. CNAME has NOTHING to do with HTTP.